# Exit code 127 - Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

I'm new to ionic. Every time i try to start by ionic serve, i encounter this problem. I have included the error log for reference.

I have tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling, clearing cache and even reinstalling nodejs from scratch.

Thank you.

[error] BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.

at unknownQuery (D:\npm\project-1\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:204:10)

at D:\npm\project-1\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:296:11

at Array.reduce ()

at resolve (D:\npm\project-1\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:237:18)

at browserslist (D:\npm\project-1\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:361:16)

at new BuildBrowserFeatures (D:\npm\project-1\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\build-browser-features.js:17:35)

at generateWebpackConfig (D:\npm\project-1\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:24:34)

at async Object.generateBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (D:\npm\project-1\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:107:20)

at async setup (D:\npm\project-1\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:73:37)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for the future endeavor at Stack overflow. Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Comment: This is a bug with Ionic and it's currently [tracked here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3869).